# Why does unity material not render semi-transparency properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transparency

I have a Unity material whose albedo is based on a spritesheet. The sprite has semi-transparency, and is formatted to RGBA 32bit.
Now, the transparency renders in the sprite, but not in the material.
How do I do this without also making supposedly opaque parts of the albedo not transparent?

I have tried setting render mode to transparent, fade, and unlit/transparent. The result looks like this:

[image: Structures are assigned opaque but acts semi transparent]

[image: Structure is assigned to be opaque but acts semi transparent]

I tried opaque, but it ruins the texture. I tried cutout, but the semi-transparency will get out or become fully opaque. (depending on cutout)

There is no code to this.

I expect the output to make the semi-transparent parts of the material semi-transparent, and the opaque parts opaque. The actual output is either fully opaque or fully "semi-transparent", which is super annoying.

### Edit

So I delayed work and I added submesh. So, it is really close to solving the problem.

[image]

It's still doing that glitch.

Comment: You try `Fade` instead

Comment: @derHugo um yeah I already tried not working

Comment: Feedback: questions are written for the benefit of future readers on _Stack Overflow_. "im typing with one hand plz fix this" warrants both an edit and a downvote. In general, seasoned readers will regard this as a form of content vandalism.

Comment: I did not know we needed to change all our post once guidelines are changed. This post was from a year ago.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay, good news and bad news. The good news is, this problem is not uncommon. It's not even unique to Unity. The bad news is, the *reason* it's not uncommon or unique to Unity is because it's a universal issue with no perfect solution. But we may be able to find you a work around, so let's go through this together.

There's a fundamental issue in 3D Graphics: In what order do you draw things? If you're drawing a regular picture in real life, the obvious answer is you draw the things based on how far away from the viewer they are. This works fine for a while, but what do you do with objects that aren't cleanly "in front" of other things? Consider the following image:

[image: A photograph of a basket containing fruit]

Is the fruit in that basket in front of the bowl, or behind it? It's kind of neither, right? And even if you can split objects up into front and back, how do you deal with intersecting objects? Enter the Z-Buffer:

[image: A simple 3D scene containing several meshes above a greyscale representation of the Z-Buffer of that scene]

The Z-Buffer is a simple idea: When drawing the pixels of an object, you also draw the *depth* of those pixels. That is, how far away from the camera they are. When you draw a new object into the scene, you check the depth of the underlying pixel and compare it with the depth of the new one. If the new pixel is closer, you overwrite the old one. If the old pixel is closer, you don't do anything. The Z Buffer is generally a single channel (read: greyscale) image that never gets shown directly. As well as depth sorting, it can also be used for various post processing effects such as fog or ambient occlusion.

Now, one key component of the depth buffer is that it can only store one value per pixel. Most of the time, this is fine; After all, if you're just trying to sort a bunch of objects, the only depth you really care about is the depth of the front-most one. Anything behind that front-most object will be rendered invisible, and that's all you need to know or care about.

That is, unless your front-most object is transparent.

[image: Four images illustrating various intersecting transparent planes]

The issue here is that the renderer doesn't know how to deal with drawing an object behind a transparent one. To avoid this, a smart renderer (including unity) goes through the following steps:

1. Draw all opaque objects, in any order.
2. Sort all transparent objects by distance from the camera.
3. Draw all transparent objects, from furthest to closest.

This way, the chances of running into weird depth sorting issues is minimized. But this will still fall apart in a couple of places. When you make your object use a transparent material, the fact that 99% of the object is actually solid *is completely irrelevant.* As far as Unity is concerned, your entire object is transparent, and so it gets drawn according to its depth relative to other transparent objects in the scene. If you've got lots of transparent objects, you're *going* to have problems the moment you have intersecting meshes.

So, how do you deal with these problems? You have a few options.

The first and most important thing you can do is limit transparent materials to areas that are *explicitly* transparent. I *believe* the rendering order is based on materials above all else, so having a mesh with several opaque materials and a single transparent one will probably work fine, with the opaque parts being rendered before the single transparent part, but don't quote me on that.

Secondly, if you have alternatives, use them. The reason "cutout" mode seems to be a binary mask rather than real transparency is because *it is.* Because it's not really transparent, you don't run into any of the depth sorting issues that you typically would. It's a trade-off.

Third, try to avoid large intersecting objects with transparent materials. Large bodies of water are notorious for causing problems in this regard. Think carefully about what you have to work with.

Finally, if you absolutely must have multiple large intersecting transparent objects, consider breaking them up into multiple pieces.

I appreciate that none of these answers are truly satisfying, but the key takeaway from all this that this is not a bug so much as a limitation of the medium. If you're really keen you could try digging into custom render pipelines that solve your problem explicitly, but keep in mind you'll be paying a premium in performance if you do.

Good luck.

Comment: Well, there are a lot of large bodies of water ingame. Is it possible for a mesh to have two textures? (based on uvs and resources) What I mean is this. One supposedly opaque quad has an opaque texture in one material. Then there is another quad, which is transparent, that has a transparent texture in another material. Is it possible?

Comment: I believe so. Essentially, each mesh can have multiple "sub-meshes", which are basically lists of triangles that share a common material. In 3D modeling programs these may be referred to as "material slots" or some such.

Comment: how much do draw calls delay the runtime

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried Transparent Shader mode, but, did you tried to change Alpha Channel values in your material color after it?
The second image seems like the Alpha in RGBA is 0, try changing it.

Comment: What do you mean? My sprite maker saves sprites along with its alpha channel.

Comment: Reading the last answer I just can think I underestimated your problem. haha..
But I had some issues like those in humanoid models, which I solved setting the Alpha channel of my texture to 255, I thought if you tried something like that, it would help.. but I don't know more if it's the case. Sorry for wasting your time.